# How do i get a String from another class? - ANDROID

Tags: java, android

i got a question for you guys. I have 2 classes:

**TelaCadastroRestauranteDAO.java - IT DOES NOT EXTENDS ACTIVITY**

and

**TelaCadastroRestaurante.java - IT DOES EXTENDS ACTIVITY**

In my first class **TelaCadastroRestauranteDAO.java**, i have a string **restauranteParseIdString** which it has a value. And i want pass this string to the other class **TelaCadastroRestaurante.java**.

*I couldn't do it with Intent, because my ..DAO class doesn't extends activity, so i can't import Intent (at least, i think that is the problem)*

---

```
public class TelaCadastroRestauranteDAO {

private static ParseObject restauranteParse;
private static String restauranteParseIdString = restauranteParse.getObjectId();
private static ProgressDialog dialog;
private static AlertDialog.Builder builderaction;

... 

}
```

and

```
public class TelaCadastroRestaurante extends Activity {

private Restaurante rest;
private Button proximoButton;
private EditText nomeRestauranteEditText, emailRestauranteEditText, telefoneRestauranteEditText;
private String nomeRestauranteString, emailRestauranteString, telefoneRestauranteString, idRestaurante;
private String voceTemCertezaCadastrarRestaurante = "Você tem certeza que deseja cadastrar o restaurante: ";
private Context contexThisClass = TelaCadastroRestaurante.this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_cadastro_restaurante);

    // i want get the string right here

    if(checkwifi()){
        setUpComponents();
        dealButtons();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why you dont use `TelaCadastroRestauranteDAO.restauranteParseIdString`. make it public first of course

Answer (score 1):

Because `restauranteParseIdString` is `static` field so to access it in other class use class name like:

```
String strDAO=TelaCadastroRestauranteDAO.restauranteParseIdString;
```

and declare `restauranteParseIdString` as `public` to access in other classes:

```
public static String restauranteParseIdString = restauranteParse.getObjectId();
```

Comment: thanks, but i figure it out.. my String in DAO class, is private... i changed for public and i could get it.

Comment: @lurdes: need to declare `restauranteParseIdString` String as `public` instead of `private` to access in other classes